# Why does instance.created_at == instance.updated_at return 'false' when an object has never been updated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance

I have an instance of a model which I'm playing with in my console. The instance is called `mz`.

```
irb(main):002:0> mz.updated_at
=> Fri, 24 Apr 2020 14:01:38 UTC +00:00
irb(main):003:0> mz.created_at
=> Fri, 24 Apr 2020 14:01:38 UTC +00:00
irb(main):004:0> mz.created_at == mz.updated_at
=> false
```

Why is this the case?

It looks to me like it should return true.

(I am trying to solve this problem for a non abstract coding problem, but best to describe it this way I think.)

Update #1...

```
irb(main):003:0> m.updated_at.to_i
=> 1587741257
irb(main):004:0> m.created_at.to_i
=> 1587741257
irb(main):005:0> m.updated_at == m.created_at
=> false
```

Confused? I still am.

Update #2 re @DennisvandeHoef

```
irb(main):002:0> m.updated_at.to_i
=> 1587741257
irb(main):003:0> m.created_at.to_i
=> 1587741257
irb(main):004:0> m.updated_at = m.created_at
=> Fri, 24 Apr 2020 15:14:17 UTC +00:00
irb(main):005:0> m.save(touch: false)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Tlk Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "tlks".* FROM "tlks" WHERE "tlks"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 48], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Spkr Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "spkrs".* FROM "spkrs" WHERE "spkrs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 65], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ActionText::RichText Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "action_text_rich_texts".* FROM "action_text_rich_texts" WHERE "action_text_rich_texts"."record_id" = $1 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."record_type" = $2 AND "action_text_rich_texts"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 74], ["record_type", "Msg"], ["name", "safe_content"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Msg Update (0.6ms)  UPDATE "msgs" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "msgs"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2020-04-24 15:14:17.833380"], ["id", 74]]
   (6.4ms)  COMMIT
=> true
irb(main):006:0> m.updated_at == m.created_at
=> true
```

Interesting that it works, but I have no idea why it would be different! Any thoughts?

Comment: Tried to reproduce this and failed - I got `true` for unchanged record. 
What will `mz.created_at - mz.updated_at` show?

Comment: Depends on your setup and your database but the records might differ by a few milliseconds which are not show when outputting to the console.

Comment: Call `to_i` on each date and you will find difference in nano seconds.

Comment: Accoring to [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/98a57aa5f610bc66af31af409c72173cdeeb3c9e/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L101) they should be equal.

Comment: @AmitPatel not to be pedantic but `to_i` on a time actually returns a timestamp in seconds. Nanosecond timestamps are 19 digits long

Comment: you are right Max. Thank!

Comment: PavelOganesyan, spikermann, @amitpatel, yazalavin, maxpleaner - see my edit

Comment: can you try something like: `m.updated_at = m.created_at; m.save(touch: false); m.updated_at == m.created_at`

Comment: Updated @DennisvandeHoef

Comment: You can see the same behavior if you do `Time.now == Time.now`. Which can be explained for the reason that spickerman explained which is that they are microseconds off from each other. If you want to compare timestamps you need to truncate them to an acceptable level of precision.

Comment: See what your update wrote into the database `...["updated_at", "2020-04-24 15:14:17.833380"]...`. 833380 nanoseconds...

Comment: Thanks @spickermann